# How to know the current position of an iterator?

Tags: rust

My problem is the following, but I would like to ask the slightly broader question in the title.

I have an iterator `a` of type `Chars` other a string. Suppose that I found an error while reading the string, and I would like to print an error message. This message should mention the position of the error in the string (line number, etc.) Is there any method in the Rust standard library which could help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Iterator::enumerate()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate).

Here is an example tailored to your use case:

```
fn one_indexed<T>((n, x): (usize, T)) -> (usize, T) {
    (n+1, x)
}
fn main() {
    let s = "abc def\nghi jkl";
    for (line_n, line) in s.lines().enumerate().map(one_indexed) {
        for (char_n, char) in line.chars().enumerate().map(one_indexed) {
            println!("character {} at {}:{}", char, line_n, char_n);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
character a at 1:1
character b at 1:2
character c at 1:3
character   at 1:4
character d at 1:5
character e at 1:6
character f at 1:7
character g at 2:1
character h at 2:2
character i at 2:3
character   at 2:4
character j at 2:5
character k at 2:6
character l at 2:7
```

Comment: It's only part of the solution, of course, as then you need to map the position you get from `enumerate` to the line/column in a human readable way. Still, I think this approach is superior to tracking the line/column in that the "happy path" does not pay the maintenance cost of updating those variables.